# As an example of domestic violence, she referred to his (him) beating her up

Tags: grammar

I came across the following sentence in this [link] ([When to use the gerund form of a verb after "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322877/when-to-use-the-gerund-form-of-a-verb-after-to)).

"As an example of domestic violence, she referred to his beating her up".

Could someone help me understand why it's "his beating her up" and not "him beating her up"?

I was not able to find similar examples online ...

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, the gerund (-ing) functions as a noun which can accordingly be modified by a possessive adjective. See https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/gerunds-pronouns/ You can also express the same content by using the pronoun "him". The semantic difference is very subtle. The possessive version emphasises the action done by "him", that is "beating". The version with the pronoun emphasises the doer, that is "the beater". There is mainly a difference in style. As the writer of the linked article argues, the "possessive version" sounds more elegant.

Comment: So “ him beating her up” is ungrammatical in this sentence?

Comment: No it isn't. It's just a matter of style (the "possessive version" sounds more elegant).

Comment: Please make a full answer. The OP is asking about the difference and possible usage of “him/his” in the sentence.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for the very detailed explanations!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the subjective case *his*, the emphasis is on the beating. Here, the phrase “beating her up” is taken as a single unit. The clause after the comma is structurally similar to sentences such as the following:

- He referred to *his notes*.
- She referred to *his eating habits*.

If you use the objective case *him*, the emphasis is on the person doing the beating, with the words “beating her up” providing more information about the “he”. The structure of the clause would then convey a similar sense to the structure of the following:

- He referred to *the man who was walking on the sidewalk*.
- She referred to *the gardener mowing the grass*.